# Program works slower when running second time after recompilation

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, qt-creator

Performance of the simple program (generate `1 200 000` unique random shuffled integers then sort them) is slower, when I run it from `Qt Creator` second time after recompilation (and all the next till the next recompilation).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iterator>

#include <cstdint>

using size_type = std::uint32_t;

alignas(64) size_type v[1200000];

// behaviour really not depends on CPU affinity
#ifdef __linux__
#include <sched.h>
#endif

int main()
{
#ifdef __linux__
    {
        cpu_set_t m;
        int status;

        CPU_ZERO(&m);
        CPU_SET(0, &m);
        status = sched_setaffinity(0, sizeof(m), &m);
        if (status != 0) {
            perror("sched_setaffinity");
        }
    }
#endif
    std::mt19937 g(0);

    for (size_type i = 1; i < std::size(v); ++i) {
        v[i] = std::exchange(v[g() % i], i);
    }
    for (size_type i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { // first output not depends on number of iterations
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::microseconds >(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Say, first time it prints;

```
97896
26069
25628
25771
25863
25722
25976
25855
25687
25735
```

and then:

```
137238
35056
34880
34468
34746
27309
25781
25932
25502
25383
```

yet another (and all further like the second and third):

```
137648
35086
34966
26005
26305
26435
25683
25440
25981
25632
```

If I recompile program, then all repeating again.

If I recompile program and run it from the console, then all outputs starting from value near the `137000`, even the first one, and looks like the next:

```
137207
35059
35035
34844
34563
34586
34466
34132
34327
34487
```

If mutters much, I build and run above program on Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.3 64 bit on `AMD A10-7800 Radeon R7, 12 Compute Cores 4C+8G` w/ 8GB RAM, SSD. Without root previlegies and without debugger on. I use `g++-7 -m32 -march=native -mtune=native -O3`, `gold` and `ccache`.

I expected inverse results, because of (maybe) branch prediction caching or some other caching (if possible at all between consecutive runs of the same code), but the results are discouraging.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. First 4 runs after each recompilation differ by ±1% only. Do you manually run the program twice, or use a script? Is the first run right after compilation? How about further consecutive runs?

Comment: If could be specific to using `std::random_device` as the seed, have you tried seeding with same number each time (and commenting out `std::random_device`).

Comment: @TheVee I manually run this program twice from Qt Creator (Ctrl + R). The first run is immediately after recompilation. Only first run is fast, all the rest are slower.

Comment: when you write "all the next.." do you mean that the result is exactly the same on all runs (except the first) ?

Comment: @user463035818 I mean that result is the same on all runs except the first.

Comment: Oh, I missed "all the next". Try a constant seed or a different random device. If anything, though however unlikely, I can possibly imagine scenarios where an actual `random_device` needs some time to regenerate entropy.

Comment: @TheVee removing `std::random_device` didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: the exact same result is quite strange, as you are sorting random numbers and with a different seed each time one would expect some deviation in the timings

Comment: Not exactly the same, there is jitter of course.

Comment: @Orient Did you try it in a plain console, without Qt Creator?

Comment: ... well thats what I was asking for

Comment: 98435 138064 137809 138019 137817

Comment: do you compile with optimizations on?

Comment: @liliscent Good catch. It matters. All runs are slow if run from console. Even first run after recompilation (w/o running from Qt Creator).

Comment: @bolov w/ and w/o optimization results are same.

Comment: What a delicate mystery :-) I'd suggest using an actual profiler. My second guess is memory allocation.

Comment: I would guess that the OS is getting another process on that core (or having it swap cores at times) for the 2nd+ runs which means some of the data is lost from the CPU cache.  What happens if you try setting the processes affinity to a single core?

Comment: @UKMonkey Not depends on cpu affinity.